# Websphere JMS: Unable to deserialize object

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am using Websphere MQ 6.x and I am getting the following exception thrown when an object is read from the queue.

```
Caused by: javax.jms.MessageFormatException: MQJMS1061: Unable to deserialize object
    at com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage.newMessageFormatException(JMSMessage.java:4982)
    at com.ibm.jms.JMSObjectMessage.getObject(JMSObjectMessage.java:289)
```

I am able to see the serialized version of the message (class) using WMQ Tool.  But when the application reads it this exception happens.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I think a early version 6.x had a problem with primitive types. Maybe its this:http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC50448

Comment: No, my class doesn't contain a Class object holding a primitive

Answer (score 0):

have you tried trying to read and write the messages from the queue using other tools besides your application?

You can try and see if you can read and write the messages to your queues using RFH Util for example or MQ Explorer to see if the problem is with your application or with the MQ infrastructure.

What is the application that is reading the message from the MQ Queue?

HTH

Manglu

Comment: I am able to connect to the queue manager and browse the messages in the queue using WMQ without any issues

Comment: As mentioned by Nicholas, i think it is time to see the entire stack trace to see what is likely causing this issue.

Comment: The rest of the log contains proprietary information which I cannot share according to the company policy.   Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the application reading the message does not have the class in it's classpath ? Or a more subtle issue, it may not be visible to the thread's context classloader.

Do you have a longer stack trace that might supply more information ?